# How do I change a form's icon to my own image?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, windows-forms-designer

How do I change a WinForm form's icon to my own image?

Comment: Project => _YourProjectName_ Properties... => Application => you can see option there to change default icon.

Answer (score 2):

See the green arrow below:

[image]

Just click the '...' button and you have to have a .ico file.  I would recommend looking at Icon Archive (Just Google it).  They have tons of free icons.

Comment: Good lookin' out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It should be a setting in the project properties.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/339stzf7.aspx

Comment: I think these are instructions to change the icon the built EXE will have. Good to know I suppose, but it's different than the icon OP asked about (the icon in the form's title bar).

Comment: Yes, they are but there is a note in there to also change each window's icon property, so i figured it would cover both scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an icon file (.ico):

1. Select the Form in the designer.
2. View - Properties Window
3. Scroll to `Icon`.
4. Click on the right (a button with "..." will appear.)

[image]

5. Select your icon.